# Need to verify and output similarities and differences of data tables in two excel sheets using testcafe. Is there an approach to do it in testcafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Compare data in two excel sheets using testcafe

I need the approach to follow to compare data in two excel sheets using testcafe

Answer (score 2):

Since TestCafe tests are Node.js scripts, you can use any third-party library for reading data from excel files.

This example shows how to compare cell values using the [read-excel-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file) npm module:

```
import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file/node';

fixture`Test Excel Files`
    .page`about:blank`;

test('Compare files', async t => {
    const rows1 = await readXlsxFile('./excel-files/1.xlsx');
    const rows2 = await readXlsxFile('./excel-files/2.xlsx');

    await t.expect(rows1[1][1]).eql(rows2[1][1]);
});
```

Comment: Acknowledged. Thank you so much. Yes I used node-xlsx lib.